# Query returning 2 distinct rows even I have used UNION

Tags: sql, t-sql

I put `union` among two select queries and still it return two row, it should return 1 row because i have used union on it. Why it returns 2 distinct rows ? It should have returned single row instead of 2 rows.

**QUERY**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUserProject]       
 (      
 @User_ID int=2
 )      
AS      
BEGIN      
       if @User_ID !=0
       begin
 select distinct (x.Project_ID),x.ProjectName,x.ID,x.IsSource,x.IsDeployement 
   from
    (
     select p.Project_ID, cp.ProjectName  
           ,ISNULL(pa.IsSource,'false') as IsSource   
           ,isnull(pa.IsDeployement,'false') as IsDeployement  
           ,ISNULL(pa.ID,0) AS ID      
     from Project p   
     inner join ProjectAssigment pa      
     on p.Project_ID =pa.Project_ID  
     --and p.UserID=pa.User_ID      
     inner join WebUsers u    
     on p.UserID=u.UserID     
     inner join ClientProjects cp      
     on cp.ClientProjectID=p.Project_ID      
     where pa.User_ID=@User_ID 
     --and pa.IsSource=1 and pa.IsDeployement=1
     union 
     select  p.Project_ID, cp.ProjectName  
            ,ISNULL(pa.IsSource,'false') as IsSource  
            ,isnull(pa.IsDeployement,'false') as IsDeployement  
            ,ISNULL(pa.ID,0) AS ID      
     from Project p   
     inner join ClientProjects cp      
     on cp.ClientProjectID=p.Project_ID
     left join ProjectAssigment pa      
     --on pa.Project_ID=p.Project_ID 
     on pa.User_ID=p.UserID        
     left  join WebUsers u    
     on pa.User_ID=u.UserID     
     and u.UserID!=@User_ID 
   ) as x
  group by x.Project_ID,x.ProjectName,x.ID,x.IsDeployement,x.IsSource
  end  
END
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it return two rows when using `UNION`??? As long as they aren't identical there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Please help us a bit. Tell us, what is your goal, the tables' structure (`CREATE` statements only with the relevant fields), sample data and your desired output based on the sample data. (In short, to answer the current question: The two records are not identical, this is why `UNION` returns two records.) Please read the article about [UNION and UNION ALL on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: That query is just messed up.  You have both distinct and group by.  One the second select you don't even link ClientProjects to ProjectAssigment.  u.UserID!=@User_ID breaks the left.  You have bigger problems then not getting the number of rows you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of 2 select queries are different, it will return two rows else if same, it will return single row when you are using `UNION`. `UNION` removes duplicates in the set, performing set union operation.

You need to use `UNION ALL`

Comment: `UNION ALL` will not return distinct values. If `UNION` do not return distinct values, `UNION ALL` will not do that. `UNION` filters duplication while merging the resultsets o the two queries, `UNION ALL` does not do any filtering. (`UNION`'s result is a subset of `UNION ALL`'s result)